# Magento: how to turn attribute to configurable

Tags: magento, attributes

Some attributes, that were used as configurable in the goods, wheren't created as configurable. So now there is an empty space in the place where there should be value  on the product card the front-end. Thus we do have this value in this good, it isn't shown on the panel for configuranle attributes.
[The product card of the good.(I'm sorry for cyrillic letters)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cLs68.jpg)

Can I change the value in the table **catalog_eav_attribute** to turn attribute to configurable?
Do I need to change smth more?

Answer (score 0):

Just go to magento admin panel. Select Main menu->Catalog->Attributes->Manage Attributes
Select your attribute -> Set "Use To Create Configurable Product" = "Yes"

[Print screen](http://prntscr.com/fmt9v1)

Comment: It is possible, when you create the attribute. If it is already created, you can't change this option from admin panel. I use Magento 1.

Comment: Oh, i've got it. The attribute should be dropdown or multiselect. So you can change it in admin panel.

Comment: Sure, otherwise how can you configure it=))
You are welcome!